# Prove that $1^3+2^3+...+(n-1)^3=0 \mod n$ iff $n \not=2 \mod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question in title.

So far I have $1^3+2^3+...+(n-1)^3= (n-1)^2(n)^2/(4)$
But I can't figure out why ONLY the only restriction on n is that it is $n \not=2 \mod 4$. Why not $n \not=3$? Or $4$?

Comment: If $n$ is not congruent $2$ modulo $4$, either $(n-1)^2$ or $n$ is divisible by $4$. The rest should be easy.

Comment: $n =2 \mod 4\iff n=4m+2$ hence RHS becomes $(4m+1)^2(2m+1)^2$ which is always odd.